# Change UIBarbuttonItems Color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How can I set `UIBarButtonItem's` color to green? I'm using **iOS 4**, there is no tint property. please help me.

Comment: Did you try my answer ? please tell me if you still have issues.

Comment: @MidhunMP: UIBarButton's color changed. but how can set title and action on it?

Comment: I have edited my answer, please check it is working or not.

Comment: @MidhunMP:Thank You so much frnd. it's working

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In iOS 4:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame=CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 60.0, 30.0);
[button setTitle:@"Green" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Here you need a green image for doing this, you are creating a custom button with this image and set it as the view of UIBarButtonItem.

In iOS 5 you can use:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Please check these links for more:

1. [UIAppearance Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
2. [User interface customization](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)

Comment: As per documentation it is available from iOS 5 onwards. His question is for iOS 4. Check it here.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Poor Midhun. Good answers to the wrong questions today :) I hate days like this :)

Comment: @rmaddy: I think you are right :) This is a bad day for me :(

Comment: @ACB: thanks for your comment, after that i noticed he was working with ios 4. :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try the below code.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 4**

This is how you can add your custom color to UIBarButtonItem

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(
        title: "Paired",
        style: .done,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(self.myAction(sender:))
      )
barButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 247/255, green: 65/255, blue: 126/255, alpha: 1.0)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case anyone is using a `customView`, you can try:

```
myButton.customView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```