# Changing the button color of a navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios6, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to change the button color without an image in the navigation bar of iOS 6?

I see on other stackoverflow posts that in iOS 5 you needed an image. Is that still true?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tint UIBarButtonItem background color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274473/how-to-tint-uibarbuttonitem-background-color) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13677703/change-uibarbuttonitems-color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the color with tint color. The following will give you a button with a red background.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
[button setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

or if using storyboard/xib there is a tint dropdown.

Comment: awesome thanks. I see some of the other posts online are obvioulsly old.